# Обработка пустых ключей массива в php

Tags: php

Вопрос достаточно спорный. Допустим есть строка, которая может меняться. И нужно выводить слова из этой строки. Мы используем функцию `explode()` Она создает массив слов. С цифровыми ключами. Допустим я хочу выводить второе слово в массиве. Я прописываю в скрипте переменную. `$data[1]` , что вызывает нужное мне слово. Однако, все хорошо, когда это слово есть. Но бывает, что в строке всего 1 слово и эта переменная вызывает ошибку. Но это понятно, переменная ж не существует. И вот вопрос. Каким образом обрабатывать такие ошибки. Нужно нормальное решение. Без использования `@` или `empty()`, и что б конструкция получилась простой. Я могу конечно обойти эту ошибку, но это будет лишний код. Помогите подобрать технологичное решение.

Comment: `if (count($data) < 2) $data[1] = '';` не устраивает?

Comment: Еще б проще сделать. В идеале, было б неплохо, что б если переменная не задана, то задавало ее дефортным значением. Но без IF и прочего.

Comment: `a = isset(b) ? b : default;`

Comment: Эдуард, это строка которую получает скрипт от телеграм бота. Разработчики не сделали отдельный ключ, для данных deep ссылок. И приходится отлавливать эти значения самому, брать их вместе с /start , но бывают случаи когда эти данные не передаются скрипту, и если есть эти элементы кода то они ошибки выдают. Я не хочу усложнять код не нужной обработкой данных.

Comment: @Денис одна строка кода сильно усложнит ваш скрипт? `$arr = array_values(array_filter($arr));`

Comment: Спасибо. Использую это решение еще где нибудь.

Comment: @Денис по вашему вопросу в первом посту это решение должно быть чуть ли не единственно правильным. Иначе получается, вы не верно сформулировали вопрос. Ответ, который вы приняли как правильный не совсем соответствует описанному вами поведению. А именно, при пустом значении ключа 1 вы не увидите ничего в браузере. А при использовании моего варианта в массиве пустых значений не будет, если хотя бы один элемент был подан на вход.

Comment: @Эдуард, текст вопроса и правда можно упростить. Однако, Ваша интерпретация к нему сложно применима. Ясно написано, что проблема в том, что неизвестно сколько токенов возвращает explode. Про массив "с дырками" в вопросе ни слова.

Comment: @Эдуард  я могу задать теперь сразу значение в переменную. Это конечно, в идеале не решение моей проблемы. Но для того что я сейчас делаю, это подходит. Если ключ пустой или его не существует, я могу записать в базу значение false и дальше его обрабатывать. И оно очень короткое. Ваше решение тоже верное, но это целая строка кода дополнительная.

Comment: @Эдуард тут даже не массив с дырками. А я жестко прописываю переменную в коде, которая иногда может оказаться и пустой. И нужно или что то в нее записать, или как то игнорировать эту ошибку.

Comment: @Эдуард это еще не все, по мимо этого у аккаунтов телеграм, может не оказаться например логина или фамилии и в массиве не будет этого значения, а в скрипте я уже жестко прописал $data['message']['chat']['username'] и вот когда я могу задать переменную на свое значение, если она пуста мне очень помогло, до этого я использовал if и empty(). И даже использовал сокращенную запись. Но я не знал что у 7 версии PHP есть еще проще решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно дополнить массив до нужной длины с помощью `array_pad`:

```
$data = array_pad(explode(', ', 'test'), 2, 'def'); // ['test', 'def']
```

В php7 есть [оператор coalesce](http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
$data = explode(' ', $str);
$word2 = $data[1] ?? '';
```

Comment: я на 7 и работаю. Спасибо. Похоже то что нужно.